# Getting 100% divs & inputs to display horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the input field to stretch the width of the available screen width, keeping the 30px div floated right on the same line. Having trouble working this one out.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div style="float:left;">
        <input type="text" style="width:100%;">
    </div>
    <div style="float:right; width:30px; border:1px solid red;">
        @
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whats wrong? I'm not sure what your asking.

Comment: I want the input field's width to be as wide as the screen width before the 30px div displays to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use [CSS calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
html, body {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
#parent {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
#parent>div:first-child {
    float:left;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
#parent>div:first-child>input {
    width:100%;
}
#parent>div:first-child+div {
    float:right;
    width:30px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>@</div>
</div>
```

---

Another way is to use `display:table/table-cell`:

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
html, body {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
#parent{
    display:table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
#parent>div{
    display:table-cell;
}
#parent>div:first-child{
    width:100%;
}
#parent>div:first-child+div{
    width:30px;        
}
#parent>div:first-child>input{
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>@</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Table cells sorted it out. Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused why you didn't just absolutely position the filling item's far border with respect to the far border, then the fixed width item according to its width.  There's no reason to fake a table to make this work.  This is what absolute positioning is for, and calc() is a portability nightmare.

Comment: Well, I personally don't like to use `absolute` because they get out of the _document flow_. As for the `display:table/table-cell` support, it only [doesn't work](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table) in lte IE7. Even [calc()](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) has good support, if you don't need to use lte IE8.

Answer (score 1):

Might as well post what one's fiddled...

```
<input type="text"><div>@</div>

* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type="text"] {
width: calc(100% - 30px);
}

div {
width: 30px;
float: right;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYNXYJ

Answer (score 0):

You want an outer container which sets the positioning and width.  Then absolutely position within it.  Then set the one on the right according to its right position and width; the one on the left according to the sides.

```
<div style="position:relative; width: 100%; height: 2em;">
  <div style="position: absolute; right: 0; width: 30px; top: 0; bottom: 0;">...</div>
  <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; right: 30px; top: 0; bottom: 0;">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you're confused about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: My answer does what your accepted answer does without leaving CSS1, in far less code, faster.

Try it before you decline.  Or don't. (shrug)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by floating only the `@` symbol, and setting an equal margin for the `input` container.

```css
.input-group {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.input-group .input {
  margin-right: 30px
}
.input-group input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.icon {
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="icon">@</div>
  <div class="input">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

if one div is 100% of the screen width, how do you imagine another div fitting on the same line?    The only thing that would make sense is to set them both as percentages equalling 100%.

```
<div style='width:90%;'>
   <input type="text" style="width:100%;">
</div>
<div style='width:10%;'>@</div>
```

Comment: Er, by floating them, like he said.  Or setting their positions.  Or making them inline block, or display table cell.  Or using calc().  Or any of a lot of other things.

Comment: I forgot that 100% doesnt actually mean the entire line

Comment: and John,  your answer doesnt make the input div 100% wide as per his instructions

Comment: Please actually try the code before arguing with it.  My code does exactly what he requested.  100% wide would mean overflowing the parent.